# Delete button - onDelete function

Tags: javascript, reactjs

My delete button worked before but now stopped working when I added a like/dislike satisfaction section for every challenge. Can someone spot the bug for me? This is message I get in the terminal when pushing the button: DELETE /allchallenges/[object%20Object] 200 1.623 ms - 214-----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

---

```
import React from 'react'
import DefaultLayout from "../layout/Default"
import Challengebox from '../components/Challengebox'
import axios from "axios";
import "./Allchallenges.css"
import { faThumbsUp } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faThumbsDown } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { faBalanceScale } from "@fortawesome/free-solid-svg-icons";
import { FontAwesomeIcon } from "@fortawesome/react-fontawesome";

class Allchallenges extends React.Component {
    constructor() {
        super()

        this.state = {
           challenges: []
        }

        this.onDelete=this.onDelete.bind(this)
        this.sortByTitle=this.sortByTitle.bind(this)
        this.sortByDescription=this.sortByDescription.bind(this)
        this.searchChallenges=this.searchChallenges.bind(this)
        this.challengestotal=this.challengestotal.bind(this)
    }

    componentDidMount(){
        axios({
            method: "GET",
            url: `${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges`,
            withCredentials: true
        })
        .then(response => {
            console.log(response)
            let challengeslist = response.data;
            this.setState({challenges: challengeslist})
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.log("You've made an error charles: ",error)
        })
    }

    onDelete(challengeId){
        axios
        .delete(`${process.env.REACT_APP_API_BASE}/allchallenges/${challengeId}`)
        .then(response => {
            const challenges = this.state.challenges.filter(challenge => challenge._id !== challengeId)
            this.setState({challenges})
        })
        .catch(err => console.log(err))
    }

    sortByTitle() {
        let challengesSortTitle = this.state.challenges.sort((a,b) => {
            return a.title > b.title ? 1 : -1
        })
        this.setState({
            challenges:challengesSortTitle
        })
    }

    sortByDescription() {
        let challengesSortDescription = this.state.challenges.sort((a,b) => {
            return a.description > b.description ? 1 : -1
        })
        this.setState({
            challenges:challengesSortDescription
        })
    }

    searchChallenges(e){ // eslint-disable-next-line
        let challengesSearch = this.state.challenges.filter(challenge => { 
            if(challenge.title){
                if(challenge.title.toLowerCase().includes(e.target.value.toLowerCase())){
                    return true 
                }   
            }
        })
        this.setState({
            challenges:challengesSearch
        })
    }

    challengestotal(){
        return `${this.state.challenges.length}`
    }

    // handleLikeDislike(e){
    //     e.preventDefault()
    // }

    render(){
        return (
            <DefaultLayout>
                <div className="challengeoverviewlist">
                    <h1>All challenges</h1>   

                    <div className="headers">
                        <button onClick={this.sortByTitle} className="sorttitle">
                            Sort based on TITLE
                        </button>

                        <button onClick={this.sortByDescription} className="sortdescription">
                            Sort based on DESCRIPTION
                        </button>

                        <button onClick={this.sortByDescription} className="sortdescription">
                            Sort based on DAREDEVILS
                        </button>

                        <input className="searchbox" type="text" placeholder="Search for a challenge title here..." onChange={this.searchChallenges} />

                        <p className="challengescounterbox">{this.challengestotal()} challenges</p>
                    </div>

                    <div className="challengeboxes">
                        {    
                        this.state.challenges.map(challenge => 
                            (
                                <div className="totalbox" key={challenge._id}>

                                    <div className="likedislikesbox">
                                        <div className="likecontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsUp} /></div>
                                            {/* onClick={(e)=> this.handleLikeDislike(e)} */}
                                                <p className="likestat">Likes{challenge.likes}</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="dislikecontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faThumbsDown}/></div>
                                            <p className="dislikestat">Dislike</p>
                                        </div>

                                        <div className="satisfactioncontainer">
                                            <div className="leftalignment"><FontAwesomeIcon icon={faBalanceScale}/></div>
                                            <p className="satisfactionstat">Satisf %</p>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <Challengebox 
                                        key={challenge._id} 
                                        id={challenge._id} 
                                        title={challenge.title} 
                                        description={challenge.description}
                                    />

                                    <button className="deletebutton" onClick={this.onDelete}>
                                        Delete
                                    </button>

                                </div>
                            ))                                                                      
                        }
                    </div>

                </div>    
            </DefaultLayout>
        )
    }
}

export default Allchallenges
```

Comment: where are you calling `this.onDelete`, and what are you passing it, and why are you passing it an object instead of a string?

Comment: In my delete button?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you forgot to pass the challenge id to the handler.

```
 <button className="deletebutton" onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
                                        Delete
                                    </button>
```

Answer (score 1):

`onClick` accepts an event object as its parameter. You have assumed it will be the id of the challenge you want to delete, so you're trying to add it to the query string. This is why you're getting the object error.

Instead, pass `onClick` an anonymous function and call `onDelete` with the id:

```js
<button className="deletebutton" onClick={() => this.onDelete(challenge._id)}>
```

Since you don't need the event, we don't include it in the function, and instead call `onDelete` with the id from the current mapped element.

Comment: ok thank you it works now, just trying to understand why is was wrong....why would this not work => <button className="deletebutton" onClick={this.onDelete(challenge._id)}> + binding of onDelete?

Comment: Because `onClick` expects to be passed a function *reference*. In the method you just gave, you're passing `onClick` the *return value* of a function call. This means as soon as your component renders, the delete function will be called in an attempt to assign the handler. Passing it an anonymous function instead is not calling it, but rather creating a new function.